# Runtime of a Modified Stooge Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I understand that the Stooge Sort algorithm works as the following:

```
Step 1: If the value at the end is smaller than the value at the start, swap them.
Step 2: If there are 3 or more elements in the list, then:

       Stooge sort the initial 2/3 of the list
       Stooge sort the final 2/3 of the list
       Stooge sort the initial 2/3 of the list again

       else: exit the procedure
```

I also understand that the runtime of Stooge sort is O(n^(log 3 / log 1.5)).

Out of curiosity, what would be the runtime in Big O notation if we completely took out Step 1 and the if condition in Step 2 (assuming array size will always be divisible by three)?

Comment: If you removed step 1, the runtime would be infinite.

Comment: @JohnDeters How is that possible? An infinite runtime implies that the algorithm never finishes, thus, doesn't work without Step 1. I am not sure why Step 1 is needed since the algorithm sorts just fine with Step 2.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon The runtime won't be infinite, but nothing will end up happening. If you drop that step, nothing ever gets swapped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

At step 2, you still need some condition to *not* call stooge sort recursively. Otherwise, sorting an array of length 10 calls sorting an array of length 10 * 2/3, which calls sorting an array of length 10 * 2/3 * 2/3, ... which, after a few steps in that way, calls sorting an array of length 0, which in turn calls sorting an array of length 0 again, and so on indefinitely.

At step 1, you still need to do some actual work. Otherwise, the function may be called sorting, shuffling, or whatever, but is in fact useless since there is no step which swaps any values.

So, to directly answer your question, the runtime would be infinite. But each of the two changes you propose breaks the algorithm.

Comment: No, I'm saying to assume array size is always divisible by 3. I'm not sure if you saw the edit I made. Regardless of whether or not it will work, I am asking for what the runtime in big O notation would be for just: sorting first 2/3 array, last 2/3 array, and then first 2/3, again. I'm assuming that the runtime will remain the same.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon Please provide an example of the initial size of the array such that its size, and the sizes of its parts in each recursive call, will be divisible by 3. The only such size I can think of is 0, and the algorithm, changed as you propose, still recursively calls itself indefinitely on it.

Comment: If we sort first 2/3, last 2/3, and first 2/3 on the following array [7, 4, 6, 2, 9, 5, 8, 1, 3], it will completely sort it.

Comment: Perhaps it's not clear what I'm asking. What I'm asking for is the runtime of the algorithm if we were only talking about sort first 2/3, last 2/3, and first 2/3, again on arrays of size divisible by 3. I'm not trying to use this algorithm for practical use. I'm just wondering. For simplicity, assume array size will never be less than 3 and is always divisible by 3.

Comment: Given that, we know that we have 3 steps to sorting the array as well as looking at the overall problem 2/3rds at a time. Thus, our recurrence turns out to be T(n) = 3*T(2/3 n) + 1. From there, we use the Master's Theorem for big o.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon The initial algorithm's "If there are 3 or more elements in the list, then:" in step 2 implements exactly your wish for "For simplicity, assume array size will never be less than 3" in the comments. So, you actually want that if?

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon And, I still feel that an exact algorithm you want does not exist, since I can't come up with an example, and you don't provide a detailed example either. The properties of non-existent objects can often be interesting, contradictory, and fun arguing for, but I'd prefer some solid ground.